# How to install synergy on RHEL5?

Tags: linux, synergy

I'm trying to build from source using CMake as recommended (http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/wiki/Compiling)

```
[d3p299@we16410 synergy-1.3.7-Source]$ ./hm.py build
Running setup...
Error: Generator not specified, use -g arg (use `hm genlist` for a list of generators).
```

So I lsit the generators:

```
[d3p299@we16410 synergy-1.3.7-Source]$ ./hm.sh genlist
1: Unix Makefiles
2: Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles
```

Ok  I need index 1, so I try:

```
[d3p299@we16410 synergy-1.3.7-Source]$ ./hm.py build -g 1 
Error: option -g not recognized
```

Maybe the syntax of the command is wrong?

```
[d3p299@we16410 synergy-1.3.7-Source]$ ./hm.py usage
Usage: ./hm.py <command> [-g <index>|-v|--no-prompts|<command-options>]
Example: ./hm.py build -g 3
```

I am running the command correctly as suggested in the help command.  What gives?

Comment: I think this should NOT be moved anywhere - it's just fine here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

works for me like a charm for Synergy 1.3.7

Looks like you're using the wrong build instructions (which are for 1.4.x).

Make sure you have cmake installed on your system.

Always check the **README** file inside the tar.gz file..

The older versions of Synergy use the standard UNIX installation procedure..

Run these commands:

```
./configure

make

make install
```

Can you try that? It should work just fine.

If you're trying to install the 1.4.2 Beta from source, that's when you'll need the 'hm' script and those new build instructions-- and yes, it seems to be broken for 1.4.2 Beta -- looks like a bug in their Beta release...

Comment: The README in 1.3.7 says "We have recently switched to CMake, to replace Automake." and "Plese read the Compiling wiki page for help with CMake:
http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/wiki/Compiling"

Comment: It further says "Instead of using the traditional GNU style `./configure; make`
commands, you will now need to use CMake."

Comment: just install cmake on your system via RPM, then do the regular UNIX install as described above -- it works fine for 1.3.7, I tried it.

Comment: `./configure; make` works but `make install` does not:

Comment: $ sudo make install 
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.